# Boost with inverter, second harmonic current

Tags: current, inverter, boost

I have a boost converter followed by an inverter to supply a load. The output frequency of the inverter is variable but relatively low (~50 Hz).
The issue I'm facing is the second harmonic current (at twice the output frequency) which is far from negligible.
The evident solution would be to have high enough bulk capacitance, but due to size constraints I can't. Do you know of any other solution? Like a non-standard compensation on the boost side?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you're asking a very technical question to a bunch of engineers, but yet you give no numbers. You need to give us some evidence to work from.

Comment: are you sure what you see is the second and not the third harmonic? to filter the current you would need a bigger inductor (not capacitor) at the output. Consider using SPWM and/or third harmonic elimination modulation method

Comment: Hi,
the output power is a sine wave, so Po=Voutout*Ioutput=Vo*Io*[sin(2wt)/2+cos(phi)/2].
If the input voltage of the system is a constant voltage, the current will have a frequency component at 2w, if I can't filter it.
Thus my question, is there any alternative to bulk filtering in this case?